# Pull content from one wordpress site to another wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, synchronization, mirror

I am trying to find a way of displaying the text from a website on a different site.

I own both the sites, and they both run on wordpress (I know this may make it more difficult). I just need a page to mirror the text from the page and when the original page is updated, the mirror also updates.

I have some experience in PHP and HTML, and I also would rather not use Js.
I have been looking at some posts that suggest cURL and file_get_contents but have had no luck editing it to work with my sites.

Is this even possible?

Look forward to your answers!

Comment: nobody will try to find solution, write code and provide to you. you need to try something, and when get some issues, open new question. I can suggest you just to use iframe instead of trying to use curl and etc. without good programming skills

Comment: @dferenc - I have been trying to use this page - it is the about page on one of the sites; https://www.elssolutions.co.uk/about-els/ 
I am not sure what you mean by the outline of the HTML?

Comment: I meant, is there a specific id within the markup of the target site that zou want to grab, or is it the entire page, or what other parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) and [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) are fine to get the *full html output* from an url. For example with `file_get_contents()` you can do it like this:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('http://elssolutions.co.uk/about-els');
echo $content;
```

However, in case you need just a portion of the page, [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) are far better options, as with the latter you also can query the DOM. Below is working an example.

```
<?php

// The `id` of the node in the target document to get the contents of 
$url = 'http://elssolutions.co.uk/about-els';
$id = 'comp-iudvhnkb';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
// Silence `DOMDocument` errors/warnings on html5-tags
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
// Loading content from external url
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Querying DOM for target `id`
$xpathResultset = $xpath->query("//*[@id='$id']")->item(0);

// Getting plain html
$content = $dom->saveHTML($xpathResultset);

echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great!
Can you just help me understand how you formed the '$id'? and also explain this line of the code?: 
// Querying DOM for target `id`
$xpathResultset = $xpath->query("//*[@id='$id']")->item(0);

Comment: I have actually just found where you got the $id from!

Comment: `DOMXPath::query` is a method which allows you to query the nodes in the DOM. A bit like you do it with javascript. The `//` part means the root node –to start from– and the rest (`[@id='$id']`) means find the element where the `id` attribute equals to the value of $id. (`[]` is also the attribute selector in _css_).

Comment: By the way, happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one on the site solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!